# Counting consecutive days of absence greater than 60 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this table called SickLeaves with Employee ID, the start and the end date of the sick leave.

```
EmpID   DateFrom    DateTo
3022    10.10.2010  13.10.2010
3022    09.11.2011  10.11.2011
3022    11.11.2011  11.11.2011
3022    13.11.2011  17.11.2011
3574    01.11.2011  14.11.2011
3574    15.11.2011  26.11.2011
3908    09.11.2011  09.11.2011
2734    09.11.2011  09.11.2011
3054    16.11.2011  16.11.2011
3054    17.11.2011  17.11.2011
3054    18.11.2011  18.11.2011
2246    09.11.2011  09.11.2011
3022    12.11.2011  12.11.2011
```

You can see that for employee 3022 there are multiple records of sick leave.

Now what I want to find out is which of these employees have a consecutive absence greater than 60 days from the present day, excluding the weekends and holidays from the table.

Emp 3022 has 4 sick leaves, but only 3 of them are consecutive.

```
EmpID   DateFrom    DateTo  ConsecutiveDaysOfAbsence
3022    09.11.2011  10.11.2011  2
3022    11.11.2011  11.11.2011  1
3022    13.11.2011  17.11.2011  4
3574    01.11.2011  26.11.2011  19
3908    09.11.2011  09.11.2011  1
2734    09.11.2011  09.11.2011  1
3054    16.11.2011  18.11.2011  3
2246    09.11.2011  09.11.2011  1
```

So only on those three I want to group how many days of absence are in total for that employee.

```
EmpID   SUMOFConsecutiveDaysOfAbsence
3022    7
3574    19
3908    1
2734    1
3054    3
2246    1
```

I managed to count out the weekends and holidays from the DateFrom and DateTo with DATEDIFF, but I have no idea how to exclude from the grouping the records that don't have consecutive dates per EmpID.

The holiday table has the following structure

```
 Date           Holyday
 01.01.2016     New Year's Day
 18.01.2016     Martin Luther King Jr. Birthday
 15.02.2016     President's Day
 30.05.2016     Memorial Day
 04.07.2016     Independence Day
 05.09.2016     Labor Day
 11.11.2016     Veterans' Day
 24.11.2016     Thanksgiving Day
 25.11.2016     Thanksgiving Friday
 25.12.2016     Christmas Day
 26.12.2016     Christmas Day
```

I would really appreciate some hints. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you to use a calendar table with all days of the year, with a field indicating if it is a working day or a holidays day (0/1). Then you can easily build a function to calculate how many working days are between two dates.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand `"I want to find out is which of these employees have a consecutive absence greater than 60 days from the present day, excluding the weekends and holidays from the table."` - can you more clearly define what you mean by consecutive and where the 60 days comes into this logic exactly? I can see that the 3 absences you highlight for `EmpID` 3022 all run consecutively (if you exclude weekends), so it this all you mean? If this employee also had been absent 7th-8th Oct 2010, would this have then been included as being consecutive with their absence from 10th-13th Oct?

Comment: Yes. 60 consecutive days of absence from the present day(without weekends and holidays); but as you can see employee 3022 had another sick leave In 2010 and that isn't consecutive, so we exclude that record since from 2010 to 2011 there is a gap and since we need employees that have at least 60 consecutive absence days from the present.